# XMLArray with different types but same element name and i:type attribute

Tags: xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I am trying to serialize some data I have into this XML format but not able to achive the same.

The Desired XML output is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Datas>
    <Data xmlns="" i:type="DataA">
      <Name>A1</Name>
      <ADesc>Description for A</ADesc>
    </Data>
    <Data xmlns="" i:type="DataB">
      <Name>B1</Name>
      <BDesc>Description for b</BDesc>
    </Data>
  </Datas>
</Root>
```

The Classes I created for serialization are as follows:

```
public class Data
{
    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DataA : Data
{
    [XmlElement("ADesc")]
    public string ADesc { get; set; }
}

public class DataB : Data
{
    [XmlElement("BDesc")]
    public string BDesc { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("Root")]
public class Root
{
    [XmlArray("Datas")]
    [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(Data))]
    [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(DataA))]
    [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(DataB))]
    public List<Data> Datas { get; set; }
}
```

I use the below method for serializing:

```
internal static string Serialize(Root obj)
{
    var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    ns.Add("i", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));

    using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, obj, ns);
        return textWriter.ToString();
    }
}
```

But the output I get is this (which is not correct):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Datas>
    <DataA>
      <Name>A1</Name>
      <ADesc>Description for A</ADesc>
    </DataA>
    <DataB>
      <Name>B1</Name>
      <BDesc>Description for b</BDesc>
    </DataB>
  </Datas>
</Root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to generate the `{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}type` attribute using `XmlSerializer`, you need to attach [`[XmlInclude(typeof(XXX))]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for all subclasses `XXX` of `Data` to a declared type somewhere in your object graph, i.e. on the `Root` class or the `Data` class itself:

```
//[XmlInclude(typeof(DataA))]  /* Could also go here if you prefer. */
//[XmlInclude(typeof(DataB))]  /* Could also go here if you prefer. */
public class Data
{
    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DataA : Data
{
    [XmlElement("ADesc")]
    public string ADesc { get; set; }
}

public class DataB : Data
{
    [XmlElement("BDesc")]
    public string BDesc { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("Root")]
[XmlInclude(typeof(DataA))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(DataB))]
public class Root
{
    [XmlArray("Datas")]
    public List<Data> Datas { get; set; }
}
```

For more information, see *Declaring Serialization Types* in [Troubleshooting Common Problems with the XmlSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302290.aspx) and also [Xsi:type Attribute Binding Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca1ks327.aspx).